# Открытие Jar через winrar

Tags: java, jar, winrar

Заинтерисовал меня такой вопрос, возможно ли сделать так, что бы jar нельзя было бы открыть с помощью winrar. Пытался завернуть в exe с помощью launch4j, но всё-равно открывает.Собственно цель защита от декомпеляции

Comment: JAR - это просто zip-архив. Если его не сможет открыть архиватор, то не сможет и сама java.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Тогда вопрос, можно ли собрать проект java, что бы он был не jar и не открывался c winrar?

Comment: Объясните в вопросе, какую цель Вы преследуете. Возможно Вы хотите защититься от декомпиляции вашего приложения, чтобы никто не получил доступ к исходному коду?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите защитить свою JAR от декомпиляции или вскрытия, то на 100% вы это не сделаете ни когда. Можно лишь усложнить задачу злопыхателям.

1. Произвести обфускацию кода.
2. Зашифровать все *.class файлы и использовать кастомный класс-лоадер, который будет их расшифровывать, при этом расшифровкой должен занимать какой-нибудь хасп.

Либо же вы можете использовать AOT (ahead-of-time) компилятор, для компиляции сразу в нативный код.

Comment: Если не сложно, подскажите какой-нибудь обфускатор которым пользуетесь

Comment: С этим вопросом не помогу, т.к. не обфусцируем код из-за наличия работы с рефлексией и ряда других причин. Посмотрите в интернете, я думаю найдете быстро и с отзывами.

Comment: гуглите proguard